# VPN Server on Windows server 2003 with command

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn, command-line-interface

Is there any way to create VPN Server using command line on Windows server 2003 ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean with means in Standard Windows? NO. Using PowerShell it may be possible, but that may involve calling win32 native methods (which you can do in powershell).

Windows turns fully scriptable only with Server 2012.